# Added PPA but apt-get update shows that it's URL is being ignored

Tags: 10.04, apt, ppa

I have just added the Handbrake PPA to my Ubuntu system using `apt-add-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases` as root. I've then run `apt-get update` but whenever I run this I get the following line in the output:

```
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/ lucid/main Translation-en_GB
```

I assume that this means that this URL is being ignored for some reason. When I try and run `apt-get install handbrake` it tells me that there is nowhere to install it from.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk`

Comment: I cannot believe that it was that simple - doh!

Actually, a serious question: the list of packages on the PPA page (https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases) just says `handbrake` - where am I meant to find out that it is handbrake-gtk?

Comment: Did you install the package using `apt-get update && apt-get install handbrake`?

Comment: From that page you'd click on the `View package details`link, then expand the dropdowns to see the individual package names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/ lucid/main Translation-en_GB
```

is an attempt to find localization packages from the PPA for your locale. There is no en_GB localization available in this PPA so it's ignored.

The PPA itself should not be ignored and be listed some where else in `apt-get update` output.